# Chart.js destroy function not working or working too well

Tags: javascript

I am making a chart in chart.js and I am able to get the information and make the graphs just fine, but whenever I add mychart.destroy() to the code the chart never gets a chance to load; I don't get any errors, the chart just never appears. I need the chart to load, then upon an event be destroyed, then render a new one upon an event. Here is the code.

```
function createChart() {
    var chart1 = document.getElementById('chart1');
    if(chart1 == chart1) {
     axios.get('run_history.json')
     .then(res=> {
         for(i=0; i<res.data.length; i++){
            res.data.map(data => {
                res.data[i].distance
                res.data[i].average_heart_rate
                res.data[i].moving_time
            });
                const chartDataResults = {
                            labels: ['Distance','BPM', 'Pace'],
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Run Stats',
                                data: [res.data[i].distance, res.data[i].average_heart_rate, res.data[i].moving_time],
                                borderColor: ['rgb(255,99,132)'],
                                backgroundColor: ['#add8e6', '#d3d3d3', '#b0c4de']
                            }]
                        };
                const chartConfig = {
                    type: 'bar',
                        data: chartDataResults,
                        options: {}
                    };
                var myChart = new Chart(
                    document.getElementById('chart1'),
                    chartConfig
                    );
                    myChart.destroy();
                };
            });
        };
        };
```

I have tried putting myChart.destroy() in several places and so far nothing has solved it. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `whenever I add mychart.destroy() to the code the chart never gets a chance to load` could it be because it got destroyed?

Comment: Why do you need to destroy a chart right after initializing it? Maybe you want to add the real question now.

Comment: I need it destroyed so that I can render a new one. I want the chart to load, then destroy upon an event, then render a new chart.

Comment: It is not a good idea to recreate and destroy charts so many times. Maybe you just want to re-render the chart with new configuration. If you still want to destroy then move `myChart.destroy();` to where the event happens, not right after initialization like that.